# PhpStorm - undefined class in Joomla project

Tags: joomla, phpstorm, undefined

I want to use PhpStorm on Joomla project but I can not use "Go to Class Declaration" (`Ctrl+B`) on main Joomla classes. For example `JFactory::getApplication()`.

But with my own functions in custom plugin that option works great.

What it can be wrong there?

- I have Joomla support plugin.
- I have docblock plugin.
- I tried invalidate caches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Legacy code

You only need that to work on legacy code. With the introduction of namespaces, most classnames have changed.

JFactory is a now non-existent class - it has been removed from the core. For compatibility's sake, a class alias is provided at runtime, so PHP can find the new class instead. PhpStorm (and other IDEs) don't know about those aliases (there are a lot more of them).

### Stubbing

To solve the problem, Joomla provides a stub, that tells the IDE where to find the new class. Just run

```
$ php build/stubGenerator.php
```

This will generate a `stubs.php` file in your project's root directory with the proper information.

### New code

For new code, don't use those old classnames - use their new name instead. The new classnames make it much more likely, that your new code will run on Joomla! 4.0.

Comment: I use windows on my PC. Also I have Ubuntu as the second system. May I do it on my Ubuntu and then transfer file to other system?

Comment: If file doesn't exist in your project, download it from official repo https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/build/stubGenerator.php